# qt lrelease windows binary?

Tags: windows, linux, qt, internationalization, binary

can someone give a link to lrelease binary for windows?

I can't seem to find it everywhere.

I have a server app that translates the ui dynamically via web translate engine (like google translate) and translates the entries in the .ts file. Now I need to generate a .qm from .ts and return it to the client.

So I need to put the lrelease utility on the server. Don't want to install the whole qt framework. Just the .exe and maybe some depending .dll-s.

// UPDATE

Thanks for replies. I managed to get it working in Windows.

Same question, but looking for Linux (Ubuntu) binary.

How can I check just lrelease dependencies.
I know it is in the qt4-dev-tools package, but it depends on almost whole Qt.
So is there any way to check only the lrelease dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download e.g. [QT for VS 2008][1], install it on some machine and copy lrelease and the required DLLs (I'd assume QtCore and QtXml) from there to the server. I don't think you'll find up-to-date standalone binaries on the net.

Comment: ok. I'll install the full SDK. I have Nokia Qt SDK and its not included there. How can I check which DLLs are required?

Comment: Try Dependency Walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ It's a free tool and shows the required DLLs.